# How to move view to the end in LinearLayout

Tags: android

I don't know how to move my `ImageView` to the right, now it looks like that

[image]

And I'd like to have something like that, so the image will stick to the right side of this `CardView`

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Try to use `RelativeLayout` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will get the desired result with a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/imageView3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

`RelativeLayout` is designed for these cases. As you can see it takes only an attribute like `layout_alignParentEnd` to achieve what you want

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

LinearLayouts have a [weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_weight) property that allows you to define how much surface area individual child views can take up. You assign a *"weight"* to child views and *"heavier"* children take up more space in the parent view.

**Note**: As others as stated, it's better and easier (and probably more efficient) to use a [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative), since it is better suited for aligning child views. Also, when using weight if aligning horizontally, it's usually wise to keep `layout_width` at 0dp and if aligning vertically, keep `layout_height` at 0dp.